# Iwasawa decomposition of $SL(2,R)$. The order of KAN/ANK/NAK..

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, matrix-decomposition

I would like to decompose a matrix with Det=1 using the Iwasawa decomposition method.
But I am confused with the proper order used in the decomposition.
In Wikipedia and in [CONRAD, K](https://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,R).pdf) the Iwasawa decomposition for $SL(2,R)$
is given as $$SL2(\mathbb{R}) = KAN$$
However, in the book of [V. Kisil](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Geometry_of_M%C3%B6bius_Transformations.html?id=A1P3h9cxgd4C&redir_esc=y) it reads
$$SL 2 (\mathbb{R}) = ANK $$
In the lectures on [$SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj8qf6kurTrAhWpmIsKHcDVAqoQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.utah.edu%2Fvigre%2Fminicourses%2Fsl2%2Fgeometry-talk.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Ce9agsimAcnTJQcamczjf) I see that $$SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})=NAK$$
Is there any difference in the above examples?
I am interested in this application to matrices multiplication so the order should play a role.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The $NAK$ and $KAN$ decompositions are equivalent, since the inverse map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ reverses the order. Since $AN=NA$, we also have $NAK=ANK$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just suspected this.